# Cannot Perform a full Root Motion Loop

Tags: animation

I'm having an issue at the moment where I need the root animation to follow a specific circular pattern, however, when I try to do this, at the last second the animation flips itself back around.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl4Jj.jpg I've included a video of the issue within this imgur link.

So essentially I need it to come to rest back at the center without suddenly looping back around when it returns to its initial pose. Both keyframes at the beginning and end are exactly the same.

[Blender file I made with the issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I6wiNsrVVgM9-Cjx5nlv4gQV3c3hnPH7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file (only the armature or even only the root bone)?

Comment: Sure I can! I had to make a new file since I didn't save the old one, but this one is doing the exact same thing anyhow. I'll add a link to my post!

Comment: if you switch from Quaternion to Euler it will be easy to fix, you can choose rotations on bone's Y axis of 90°, 0°, -90°, -180°, -270°. There's a problem with the Quaternion last interpolation, Quaternion seems painful when you go over a certain angle but someone will be more accurate than me. Also, why don't you use a Follow Curve constraint all along your curve?

Comment: Thanks Moon! And to be honest, I tried that but had no idea how to keyframe it into the animation so that when I exported the FBX, it was still following that same path! I tried to figure it out but got lost somewhere along the way. Figured this way would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch from *Quaternion* to *Euler* it will be easy to fix, you can choose rotations on bone's Y axis of 90°, 0°, -90°, -180°, -270°. There's a problem with the *Quaternion* last interpolation, *Quaternion* seems painful when you go over a certain angle but some Blender experts will be more accurate than me. Also, as you're trying to make something rotate around a circle, you could use a *Follow Curve* constraint.